# Is there an Eclipse shortcut behaves just like double click using mouse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I notice the Eclipse has a very handy feature of double click: it can select text block, or select contents between surrounding quotes, So is there a shortcut available to do just this?
Thanks.

By the way, i'd like to know if there is shortcut to go to the next TODO/FIXME position.

Comment: why did you accept the answer? ALT SHIFT UP is certainly NOT the same. Now you'll never get the correct answer (and I was looking for it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the double click behaviour is the same as ALT-SHIFT-UP (for example selecting the text block, but not all of it. For example, when there is content between surrounding quotes, the alt-shift-up shortcut will select the quotes as well...

Comment: no down vote, but this not work in eclipse to select the word under cursor as double click would. So i dont understand the solution versus the question.

Answer (score 8):

Regarding the next TODO/FIXME position, there are 2 buttons in the toolbar - 'Previous Annotation' (the icon has an up arrow) and 'Next Annotation' (the icon has a down arrow) - which allow you to move from one annotation to another. Annotations are the markers in the editor - errors, warnings, breakpoints, TODOs etc. You can configure which annotations should the buttons traverse through by clicking on the dropdown (inverted triangle) icon next to the toolbar buttons.

Keyboard shortcut for 'Next Annotation' is 'Ctrl+.', these are also shown if you hover over the toolbar buttons.

PS: You might also find it useful to glance through the [JDT tips and tricks](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html) document. The above mentioned toolbar buttons are also described in the document.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, i would choose this as the answer if i could choose two.

Answer (score 1):

if you are running windows (XP or newer)
you can use - **MouseKeys**

an accessibility feature 
to start it press <kbd>Alt + Shift + NumLock</kbd>
or [through the control panel](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-a-Keyboard-to-Click-Instead-of-a-Mouse) --> accessibility center --> mouse - Mouse Keys

now when you the NumLock is On you can use the number pad keys to move the mouse pointer, or more to the point, you can use the '5' key the same way you'd use the mouse's left button. 
'55' is the same as double click.

the mouse will continue to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Linux KDE -> System Settings -> Input Devicec -> Mouse -> "..move mouse by keyboard .." .. in Eclipse doublclick on 5

..but you will loose numlock keyboard