# Eclipse hotkey for the mouse double click?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, xhtml, hotkeys, eclipse-3.6

This is a  [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672880/is-there-an-eclipse-shortcut-behaves-just-like-double-click-using-mouse)  but accepted a wrong answer.

I am looking for a way to get a hotkey which selects text like when double clicking in eclipse.

e.g. i have

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{hashmap['somekey']}">
```

If i double click on somekey i get `somekey` selected, if I double click the very same spot again it selects `#{hashmap['somekey']}`

I know about alt+shift+uparrow but that's just not gonna work for this scenario.